# Deployment of war file on redhat openshift

Tags: spring, git, openshift

I created a spring mvc application (java based configuration no web.xml, no any xml anywhere) in eclipse as a dymamic web application project.I uploaded the war file to my tomcat 7 cartridge using git as documented here https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges

git finishes with a "deployment completed with status: success" message but when i try to access the deployed app under http://ashken-f00fc7c8.rhcloud.com/webservice/ it returns a http status code 404 yet on my local machine everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a result of java versioning hell. I had compiled my project with java 8 which is not yet supported by the tomcat 7 catridge. so downgrading to java 7 solved the issue. java 8 is supported by the openshift DIY catridges though.

Comment: Worked for me too.